# Difference between local and remote nmap - trying to set up mysql server remote access

Tags: mysql, nmap

I am try to set up mysql remotely. I have followed a number of guides such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627421/mysql-unable-to-connect-with-remote-server), and I have ended up using nmap to see what ports are open.

When I am on my laptop, `nmap -P0 <server>` gives:

```
Nmap scan report for <> (ip.address.here)
Host is up (0.054s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

So it doesn't show port 3306 being open.

However on my server (Ubuntu 14.04), if I run `nmap -P0 localhost` I get the following:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00064s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Which implies that the port is open as it should be. What could be causing the discrepancy? (Admittedly this is my first time using nmap). Is this the reason I can't connect to my mysql server?

Additionally, from my laptop (windows using linux subsystem) `telnet <host> 3306` gives an error saying that the remote resource is not available.

Comment: It means that the service is listening on the loopback interface only. You need to make it listen to the interface you are actually planning to use.

Answer (score 1):

The `nmap` report on your laptop includes the line:

> Not shown: 997 filtered ports

Here, *filtered* indicates that there’s a firewall blocking access to all ports other than 22, 80 and 443. This contrasts with the output from `nmap` when run on the server itself:

> Not shown: 995 closed ports

In this case, *closed* simply means that no process is listening on the 995 tested ports.

---

The firewall could be running on the server itself (if running on a GNU/Linux system, this can be checked by running `iptables -L`) or it could be running on some intermediate gateway.

If you require external access to MySQL, you would need to configure the firewall to also allow external access to Port 3306.  I would also recommend that you configure it to allow access only from your own IP address – or that of your ISP’s [autonomous system (AS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29).

Comment: How do I check whether or not there's a firewall running on the server? The server isn't running selinux for example

Comment: The server is run as an Azure virtual machine (an older version). I have perused the options available on Azure and can't see anything that suggests they are blocking specific ports.

Comment: [Here's](https://pastebin.com/8yvuJM8F) the output of `iptables -L`. Does anything look fishy there? I can't see anything that would imply the port is blocked, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running some  distribution of GNU/Linux so I've updated my answer to show how you might check if Netfilter is being used to block traffic. I have no familiarity with Azure but that would be a different question.